# Spring context:property-placeholder ignore resources not found

Tags: spring, properties, config

I'd like to have some resources required but ignore other one if its missing... How to do that? As I see it I can only do

```
<context:property-placeholder
    ignore-resource-not-found="true" 
location="required.properties, not-required-override.properties" />
```

Which affects every config listed mentioned there.

// EDIT
This is a working example

```
<bean id="requiredProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:storage.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:log4j.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:mailing.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder
    properties-ref="requiredProperties" ignore-resource-not-found="true"
    location="file:\${user.dir}/config/cvnizer.properties" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a `PropertiesFactoryBean` element for the required dependencies and simply wire the properties to the `<context:property-placeholder />`.

```
<bean id="requiredProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:file1.properties,classpath:file2.properties" />
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="requiredProperties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" location="not-required-override.properties" />
```

The properties will me merged at runtime so you can still override when a properties file is read.

Comment: Ok :). But how to load them from the classpath as it used to be? It thinks that classpath:x.properties is a file when I use util:properties which wasn't the case

Comment: The same... The location used in either namespace honors the `classpath:` prefix... I modified my anwser to include the classpath prefix.

Comment: I have updated my question with my current config, please answer :)

Comment: Use **locations** instead of **location** for the `<util:properties />`.

Comment: My wrong, thought they added it in the newest Spring release, they didn't. Use the underlying `PropertiesFactoryBean` instead of the namespace. (See modified answer).

Answer (score 0):

i think you can add like this also :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/properties/config.properties" order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Comment: This will only work if it is a web project... and you may not expect the config.properties file to be in the exact same place